# Why doesn't Datastore store lower-case struct properties even though the struct is in the same package?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

```
package test

import (
    "net/http"
    "google.golang.org/appengine" 
    "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore" 

)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler) 
}


type myStruct struct {
    test string
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var ctx = appengine.NewContext(r)   

    datastore.Put(ctx, datastore.NewKey(ctx, "myStruct", "mykey", 0, nil), &myStruct{ test: "foo" } )

}
```

The above code will store the entity and its key name in the Datastore, but it does not store the property value "foo" unless I capitalize the property name to "Test". I thought upper case is not necessary when a variable is in the same package? I'm using the local development server.

Comment: Because for the lib `datastore`, your package is not "the same package".

Comment: The `datastore` package is doing the storage, it is a separate package from the `test` package and therefore it has no access to lowercase fields defined on types inside that package.

Comment: Thanks, I falsely thought the same package meant calling the type from the same package as the type.